# How can you see the previous name of a renamed file in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I want to reconstruct the entire history of a given file, across renames.  I know that the `follow` flag to `hg log` will show me revisions in which the file, under it's previous name, was modified.  But how can I see the previous name?  A `-v` to `hg log` will show file names in each revision, but if there are enough names I won't be able to deduce which one it was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perform in cycle log by below example

```
hg log -r "adds(Seeker.txt)" --template "{file_copies}"
```

> Seeker.txt (Искатель.txt)

Output (as Lasse wrote) is "NewName (Oldname)"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following two extra flags:

```
-v -C
```

I tested this in a repository, adding test1.txt and test2.txt, and then in the same commit I renamed them to test3.txt and test4.txt respectively, and this is what the log looked like if I asked for the log of test3.txt:

```
[D:\Temp\hg] :hg log test3.txt -v -C -f  
changeset:   1:54dac6d79938
tag:         tip
user:        Lasse V. Karlsen <lasse@vkarlsen.no>
date:        Mon Oct 31 08:10:36 2011 +0100
files:       test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt test4.txt
copies:      test3.txt (test1.txt) test4.txt (test2.txt)
description:
renamed

changeset:   0:89213dc6f36f
user:        Lasse V. Karlsen <lasse@vkarlsen.no>
date:        Mon Oct 31 08:10:25 2011 +0100
files:       test1.txt test2.txt
description:
initial
```

Granted, it isn't super-easy to spot the files, but you *can* see it.

Comment: File with new current name **was added to repo** after copy|rename old file, yes? Mercurial have now revsets, which can be used in -r parameter. hg log -r "adds(current-filename-pattern)" show revision, where last rename happens

Comment: Thanks Lasse, this will be useful too at times.